# MSDeploy "The underlying connection was closed: The connection closed unexpectedly"

Tags: web-deployment, msdeploy, azure-deployment, microsoft-web-deploy

I am attempting to publish my web deploy package to azure using msdeploy.exe. It seems that the input parameters required such as /M, /U, /P have been filled in correctly but something is going wrong and the error is not descriptive enough. Has anyone seen this problem before or know where to look?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. the url placed on the /m parameter must have *https://* prepended and */msdeploy.axd* appended. Here is a screenshot of the readme that was generated with the web deploy package. This documentation led me to realise my error.

[image: readme capture]